# Determine filesystem type of given file in Java

Tags: java, filesystems

Is there something similar to `statfs` in Java to determine the filesystem type of a given file? More specifically I'd like to determine if a file provided by a user is on a shared or local filesystem. I'm going to use this information to determine if the application is opening several identically named files on the local filesystem of a distributed application, or one shared file.

I suppose if I can get something like "NFS", "Lustre", "EXT3", etc either as a string or an enumeration then I can program a mapping to shared/not shared. Let's assume the file exists and is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `FileStore`

```
String format = getFormat(Path.of(file.getPath()));

String getFormat (Path path) {
    return Files.getFileStore(path).type();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no - Java does not provide access to the information that you're looking for.

I think that your only real option is to write a shared library, and use either JNI or JNA to access it.